# Android, Espresso, ListView: How scroll to item and check this item?

Tags: android-espresso

CursorMathcer, ListView. I has list of 10 items. 
Every item has 3 properties.

- caption
- subcaption
- age

On listView show only **caption**, **subcaption**.

My test:

```
onData(withRowString(Item.CAPTION_COLUMN_NAME, "Some_caption")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

OK. This test pass and scroll to item with caption **Some_caption**.

But I want to test(by Espresso) that this item's property **age** = 45. How I can do this?

Comment: It does not matter that the list shows, onData() matches against the item in the adapter, not the actual view. You should be able to match the same item by matching against against a different column

Comment: I try:  onData(allOf(withRowString(Item.CAPTION_COLUMN_NAME, "Some_caption"), withRowInt(Item.AGE_COLUMN_NAME, 45)))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));  ---> but I get error: android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80)